# How do I give global access to a file in a private folder?

Tags: filesystems, files

For example, I want all the files in `/home/trusktr/Downloads/` to remain hidden from other users, except for one.

I tried `chmod 777 /home/trusktr/Downloads/someFile.avi` but someFile.avi is still invisible to other users.

How do I make only someFile.avi visible to all users?

RELEVANT INFO PERHAPS:

```
┌─[21:48:25/starlancer/trusktr/~]
└─╼ ls -ld /home/trusktr
drwx------ 80 trusktr users 4096 Jan  9 21:29 /home/trusktr/

┌─[21:48:34/starlancer/trusktr/~]
└─╼ ls -ld /home/trusktr/Downloads
drwxr-xr-x 8 trusktr users 4096 Jan  9 20:57 /home/trusktr/Downloads/

┌─[21:48:43/starlancer/trusktr/~]
└─╼ ls -l /home/trusktr/Downloads/someFile.avi 
-rwxrwxrwx 1 trusktr users 2575522316 Jan  9 20:40 /home/trusktr/Downloads/someFile.avi*
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `drwx------` on your home directory is preventing other users from traversing it, i.e. seeing the Downloads folder and its contents.  You can let others through to see files they know the path to but prevent them from listing your files with `--x` perms, so you'll want to `chmod 711 /home/trusktr`, and check that other files and directories in there have appropriate permissions.

Comment: Wow, great fact! That's the tiny piece of knowledge I was missing all along.

Comment: Any idea why making a symbolic link to it in some other global folder doesn't let users read the file through the symbolic link, but why using real links (i.e. not using the `-s` switch) works just fine?

Comment: Symbolic links are nothing but a textual pointer to the file - "the file you're looking for is really at ../foo.bar, look there."  That's why the permissions on them are always 777. Hard links are  normal files, they just happen to point to the same spot (inode) on the hard drive that another file does.